# Problems with samsung Pivotal web services and volley, Android application

Tags: android, android-volley, pivotal-web-services

I have a pivotal service but when accessing the developed Android application that serves but when I use the application on a Samsung, it doesn't work, the following error is out:

> java.net.UnknownHostException: host == null

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify. Volley is a client side library which you will deploy to a device.

Pivotal Web Services is a cloud based PaaS that can host web applications. It appears from your error that you haven't specified a URL for your client? Are you having issues with the server your volley client is trying to access?

Comment: Well, I just saw that that is giving me problems is the api 21 , android 5.0 , because if I puebo consume the Web service from another telephone (with another Api ) if it works, it will be a configuration pivotal or cell ?, the the consumer service and volley framework of spring and gives me the same error ( Host == null )